# Font warning Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts

After upgraded ubuntu from 15.04 to 16.04, I have problem with font. Font warning libreoffice and Text Subject on libreoffice blur (see attachment). 
what should i do with the problem? That's problem with font or vga driver on ubuntu? Please help. :-(
FYI : I'm using Acer aspire ES-551 with amd radeon R7 M265 with 2 Gb dedicated RAM.

[image]

Update for details font

[image]